# xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default under Debian 11, primary monitor via Display Port

Tags: debian, xrandr, intel-graphics

I tried to install Debian 11 yesterday but my screen resolution is stuck at 800x600 whereas I use a 8K monitor. xrandr says:

```
xrandr --verbose
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600
default connected primary 800x600+0+0 (0x524) normal (normal) 0mm x 0mm
        Identifier: 0x523
        Timestamp:  54096
        Subpixel:   unknown
        Clones:    
        CRTC:       0
        CRTCs:      0
        Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                    0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
                   filter: 
        non-desktop: 0 
                supported: 0, 1
  800x600 (0x524) 36.000MHz *current
        h: width   800 start    0 end    0 total  800 skew    0 clock  45.00KHz
        v: height  600 start    0 end    0 total  600           clock  75.00Hz
```

The information about my graphics card is below:

```
#inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel driver: N/A 
  Display: server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: vesa 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting resolution: 800x600~75Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.3.5
```

My graphic chipset is Intel Graphics UHD 770. What can I do to solve this problem?

N.B: There are similar questions on StackOverflow but for different hardware, I use neither an AMD GPU nor an Nvidia GPU, think about twice before closing mine as duplicate. I already tried modifying Grub settings.

Comment: Have you updated your system(apt upgrade/update) and have you searched for a suitable graphics driver?

Comment: I have updated and upgraded my system. I just know that the X server uses vesa. Should I reconfigure the Xorg server?

Comment: xserver-xorg-video-intel is already installed by the way.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127466/cannot-use-highest-resolution-xrandr-does-not-list-mode-intel-gpu-dp-to-dvi-a maybe cable/adapter

Comment: I already used this cable with another machine. There is no adapter in my current configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add bullseye-backports to your source lists, run `apt install -t bullseye-backports linux-image-amd64` and reboot. The kernel 6.0 solves the problem. Upgrading to Debian Bookworm is an even better solution.

This solution was suggested by a Debian user on the official Debian IRC channel and I confirm that it works.